# How to copy a struct to char

Tags: c, struct

```
MES_CRD mesCR;
if (pDspMng->reponse_json != NULL && flag == true) 
{  
   strcpy (reponseJson, (char*)mesCR);
   SIItrace (7, CV_NIV_GRA_INFO, routine, "Le contenu Json est : %s<", reponseJson);
   result = json_loads (reponseJson, 0, NULL);
}
```

MES_CRD is a structure.
i want to copy the content of structure mesCR into reponseJson.

Comment: Json is text, while structures are binary. Are you sure you understand correctly what you're trying to do?

Comment: No idea what these types are, but for raw copy you should use `memcpy`

Comment: Copy in what way? A straight up byte copy or turning every member of the struct into it's textual representation?

Comment: If you want to convert something to JSON, you'll have to write code that actually encoded the data using the JSON protocol. That is a conversion between representations, not a copy.

Comment: @Blindy : char reponseJson;

Comment: If that's supposed to be an answer to my question, then your actual answer is no. You can't even call `strcpy` with a `char`, you need a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I want to copy the content of the struct mesCR into the string reponse_json , how we can use memcpy please ?

Comment: Are you trying to cast a struct object to a char and then copying it :)? Maybe you should grab the member variable ? (char*)mesCR.foo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if (pDspMng->reponse_json != NULL && flag == true) 
                {   
                    memcpy (reponseJson, &mesCR, sizeof mesCR);
                    SIItrace (7, CV_NIV_GRA_INFO, routine, "Le contenu Json est : %s<", reponseJson);
                    result = json_loads (reponseJson, 0, NULL);
                }
```

Comment: That is not producing JSON-formatted data.